Entering an float, double or integer value in c gives out as 0 or gibberish
`#include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>
 #include<math.h>

    int main()
    {
    double r,c;
    const float PI=3.14;

    printf("enter radius:\n");
    scanf("%lf",&r);
    printf("\n Your radius is: %lf",&r);
    return 0;
    }

`
If i input 5, the next print statement shows the output as 0

You need &r for scanf, but not for printf.

You should also check the return value from scanf to make sure it's 1.  Otherwise you won't detect when a bad number has been entered.  And as mentioned, you're passing a pointer to printf instead of a double.  Your compiler should have warned about that, so be sure to enable warnings, and don't ignore them.

Does your compiler show some warning when you provide an address while a double is expected?

The conversion specifiers for scanf and printf require different arguments.

scanf must be able to write the result of the extraction from stdin to the variable. That's why you must supply a pointer to the address where it should write the result, &r.
printf needs the value held by the variable, so you shouldn't supply the variable's address but the value it holds, r.
Providing the wrong argument for the conversion specifier in either scanf or printf makes the program have undefined behavior which means that it could print or do just about anything. That's why you get "0 or gibberish".

Other notes:

While %lf is required when extracing a double with scanf, it's not needed when using printf to print a double. %lf (that was added for printf in C99) and %f means the same thing in printf. When checking what conversion specifier to use, read the documentation for scanf and printf separately.
Always check that scanf succeeded. It returns the number of successful extractions, which in your case should be 1 since you want to extract one double.

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    double r;

    puts("Enter radius:");

    if (scanf("%lf", &r) != 1) {  // if it doesn't return 1, it failed
        fputs("Invalid radius entered\n", stderr);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    printf("Your radius is: %f\n", r); // not &r
}

